# Present VC from a framework -- use keyWindow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

I'm building an SDK that presents a VC. I of course don't know what the VC architecture of the consumer's app will look like, so I'm looking for the most bulletproof way to present it.

I wrote this:

```
// Get key window
UIWindow* keyWindow;
for (UIWindow* window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
    if ([window isEqual:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow]) {
        keyWindow = window;
        break;
    }
}

[keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the best way. The keyWindow is the first responder window, however, is this the best window to present a VC from when you're writing SDK-level code that doesn't know the app's architecture?

Comment: I have seen another approach in some libraries: objects has delegate which asks for a `UIViewController` that should be used for presenting framework's controllers. Is that appropriate for you?

Comment: @Azat Yeah, that actually became the obvious answer after looking at this a little bit more - have the consumer pass the appropriate VC.